# R XML pkg. Namespace is not defined

Tags: xml, r, xpath, xml-parsing

I have the following code

```
parseBodyTemperatureTestingOnly <- function(sourceName) {
  doc <- XML::xmlTreeParse(sourceName, handlers=list('comment'=function(x,...){NULL}), asTree = TRUE)
  root <- XML::xmlRoot(doc)

  pcm <- XML::getNodeSet(root, '//mlhim2:pcs-c9be15da-7708-412b-85a6-fbe85c8f56ac', c(mlhim2='http://www.mlhim.org/ns/mlhim2/'))
```

then it goes on to process pcm.  All works well.  But, I get a message in the R Console

```
Namespace prefix mlhim2 on pcs-a768a3d0-c7e8-435d-b1db-cd7211aba6bc is not defined
```

and everywhere else that an element is prefixed with 'mlhim2'.  Without the prefix the code doesn't work. IOW the XPath doesn't find the element.

How do I suppress this message or what do I fix in my R code to avoid getting it?

Comment: Wrap the call in `suppressMessages` and you won't see the messages.

Comment: Didn't work. I guess this isn't a 'simple diagnostic message'.

Comment: This appears to run without error for me, using the example code from `?getNodeSet` `doc = xmlParse(system.file("exampleData", "tagnames.xml", package = "XML"))` (of course it returns an empty list since there aren't any nodes like that in that XML). Perhaps it's something to do with your XML??

Comment: If the `XML` package uses `cat` rather than `message` you can wrap in `capture.output`. If it is a warning, you could use `suppressWarnings`. (if it is uses `message()` then `suppressMessages` would work, but you have said it doesn't). It's not an error, is it?

Comment: supressWarnings does work.  However, every call to getNodeSet has to be wrapped? Certainly there is some overhead with that?  Seems as though there should be a setting somewhere to handle this.

Comment: Can you provide a sample document? This is probably a "namespace" issue and it's usually easier to show what to do with an example of the file (or at least the namespace definitions from the file).

Comment: Here is a GIST https://gist.github.com/twcook/520cdc8ea04a00bd4de0 BTW: Even adding the xsi namespace to the getNodeSet cal doesn't help.